# How to interpret packaging information in Datasheet

Tags: pcb-design, datasheet

I'm trying to create a part for Fritzing and I am struggling to interpret the packaging size in the datasheet.
[image]

In the notes it is said that the sizes are in mm, ok with that, but how should these numbers be interpreted? A division or max/min does not make sense.

Comment: Just FYI, the note about **"JEDEC MO-187 variation BA"** is an industry-standard name for this type of package - jedec.org is the standards organization, MO-187 is their Mechanical Outline for "Plastic Low/Thin/Very Thin Shrink Small Outline Package, 0.65 AND 0.50 Pitch. (H)(L,T,V)SR-PDSO." Within that standard MO-187, variation BA is specific to that lead pitch and number of pins. So you might check whether your CAD layout system might already have a generic "JEDEC MO-187 BA" package decal. If not, consider using that name for the decal. Will make it easier to find next time.

Comment: Why d9es max/min not make sence? That’s what the accepted answer states it is.

Comment: No measurement is ever exact.  They are giving you the range of possible values by showing the min and max possible.  2.90 to 3.10 is the same as saying 3.00 +-0.1.  I don't understand what you expect them to do.  It's physically impossible to make the part perfect, so they have to tell you what the ranges of values are.  The real question is how you think min/max *doesn't* make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Nick says, it's the maximum and minimum value that dimension can be.

In your example the width of the chip can be between 2.9mm and 3.1mm. Some datasheets would instead put "3mm ±0.1mm" which amounts to the same thing.

To get the nominal value you can subtract the lowest from the highest, divide by two, then subtract the result from the highest value.

- 3.1mm - 2.9mm = 0.2mm
- 0.2mm ÷ 2 = 0.1mm
- 3.1mm - 0.1mm = 3mm

No manufacturing system is perfect, and you have to allow certain tolerances in your design to allow for these inaccuracies.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. So it is more "secure" to use always the nominal value in design?

Comment: It depends on what you are doing. For pads you have to make sure that they are big enough for the entire possible range - so for a width like that you would maybe extend them out an extra 0.1mm and in to the centre of the chip an extra 0.1mm - but based around the nominal.

Comment: Frankly @the_grandson you should be using the recommended landing pattern and NOT the packaging information. On the opa335 data sheet, it's on the following page ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is max/min:

```
3.10mm  max
2.90mm  min
≈ 3mm   nominal
```

*[ Why did max/min initially not make sense?

I don't see why max/min wouldn't make sense. ]*

Comment: I was not aware that the size of the chip could suffer some kind of variation, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @the_grandson - **Everything** has some kind of variation. Manufacturing parts to atomic tolerances is kinda expensive.

Comment: The portion of the IC package that's this dimension corresponds to is made with epoxy.  When the epoxy cures, it shrinks.  The amount of shrinkage can vary (more so than, say, pitch between the stamped metal IC leads).

Answer (score 4):

Max on top

Min on bottom

In some countries the comma is used in place of a decimal point.